# How to keep custom front end cookie from being deleted

Tags: magento-enterprise, cookie

I'd like to capture additional customer information while they are checking out as a guest and store the data in a cookie. The problem I am experiencing is that if the user leaves the checkout page, the cookie is deleted. I'm wondering if anyone knows where this behavior comes from and what I can do to keep this cookie when the session is apparently cleared.

I've added a script in the footer that will create a cookie based on the page the user is on (needs to be the checkout page) and if they are a guest:

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('lead', $customer->getEmail(), time()+31536000, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate cookie var in observer after checkout or get customer email form order after checkout success state.

Comment: Thanks @Bashev, What if the customer doesn't checkout but rather navigates elsewhere? Should I still be able to recreate it in Observer? I'm not sure where in Observer the session is being cleared. I've played around with removePersistentCookie and _expirePersistentSession